# YouTube Subscribe Button (embed) doesn't work

Tags: html, button, youtube, youtube-api, subscribe

I have a problem with the new embedable Youtube Subscribe Button. When I try to use this code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="youtube" data-layout="default"></div>
```

no button appears. I am running a html5 file from hard drive and I even tried to download this js file and run from the same location, but nothing happened.
The code works perfectly with "online html editors" but not in my file.

I can use iframe option and it works (

```
<iframe data-gapiattached="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="25px" width="174px" style="padding-right: 10px"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/subscribe_embed?bsv&amp;usegapi=1&amp;channel=Youtube">
</iframe></h6>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

) but I want to use the "full layout" and I am wondering why can't I use any jscript-based buttons like facebook "like" - only iframe.

any tips for a newbie? ;)

Answer (score 2):

> I am running a html5 file from hard drive

This is your problem. Run it over HTTP instead. Install a local webserver if need be.